# need to delete an element from array nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image]

how do i delete a productid say 5bbee0b7e5fcb61df834f7d6 from this arrat have tried

```
router.post('/empty-cart', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("user" + req.body.user + ",product" + req.body.productId);
  slug = req.body.productId;
  user = req.body.user;
  User.findOne({ _id: user }, {
    $pull: { productId: slug }
  }, function(err, model) {})

  console.log(slug);
  meanlogger.log('trash', 'Emptied cart', req.user);

  res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
});
```

but seems like it wont apply for arrays as it considers only 1st element looking for suggestions

Comment: You have to use $pull with update, please refer to: 

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-all-items-that-equal-a-specified-value

You will get a better Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way. You should find document first, then pull by ObjectId.

```
router.post('/empty-cart', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('user' + req.body.user + ',product' + req.body.productId);
    const slug = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.productId);
    const user = req.body.user;
    User.findOne({ _id: user }, function (err, model) {
        if (err) return res.redirect('/error-page');
        if (!model) return res.redirect('/notfound-page');
        model.productId.pull(slug);
        model.save(function (err) {
          if (err) return res.redirect('/error-page');
          console.log(slug);
          meanlogger.log('trash', 'Emptied cart', req.user);
          res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hey Enxtur thanks for the answer seemed very much right but gave an error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'productId' of null for this line model.productId.pull(slug);

Comment: In your case, user not found by your input as req.body.user. Check your data dude :) and I edit my post for checking errors and model

Comment: yeah you are right that solved the issue i was retreving product id both end which led to error thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$pull` with `findOne` you should to use `update`

```
router.post('/empty-cart', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("user" + req.body.user + ",product" + req.body.productId);
  slug = req.body.productId;
  user = req.body.user;
  User.update({ _id: user }, { $pull: { productId: slug } }, function(err, model) {
    console.log(slug);
    meanlogger.log('trash', 'Emptied cart', req.user);
    res.redirect('/shopping-cart');
  })
});
```

this is the correct way.

Comment: thanks for response my query is i have an array productid and im doing nothing to loop through that array so cant achieve the requirement

Comment: have you tried with `update`? if so, you will achieve your requirement. Query is tested and working fine, may be you have issue with `user`. Try to print and check the query.

Comment: yes i have been using update only now someone suggested to use findone let me test with user as you suggest